# program unexpectedly closing

Tags: vb.net, debugging, xaml

Having issues on my first XAML application I have created in VB.net using Visual Studio 2010. Every time I run it and I want to click on the apply button (I am meant to input data in some fields and then click the apply button and that just shows a messagebox.show of what I have entered) the program crashes. I am running Windows 7 x64 ultimate edition. Any ideas?

The event log shows the below:

Faulting application name: CreditCard.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4ceafa3a
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdbdf
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b727
Faulting process id: 0x14d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb8b5a4900b2cb
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Chohan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\chapter6\CreditCard\CreditCard\bin\Debug\CreditCard.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 8eba45a2-f74d-11df-8e1c-506313a0ad71

---

Also:

Application: CreditCard.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidCastException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(System.String, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(System.String)
   at CreditCard.MainWindow.btnApply_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at CreditCard.Application.Main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd actually read the exception stack, you would find the error yourself. It's in your Apply button event handler:

System.InvalidCastException Stack: at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(System.String, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo) at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(System.String) at **CreditCard.MainWindow.btnApply_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)** at

The conversion from a string to a Double is not handled correctly

Comment: yep - figured it out - damn typo on part of my coding! Went over it a million times and then looked at it step by step and finally realised! Thanks for the help though - you helped narrow down where I should be looking.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a `String` to a `Double` and it's throwing an exception.

`ToDouble(System.String, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)`

Comment: yep - figured it out - damn typo on part of my codding! Went over it a million times and then looked at it step by step and finally realised! Thanks for the help though - you helped narrow down where I should be looking.

Answer (score 0):

System.InvalidCastException

if you are inputing strings in the textbox and parsing it as integer or a double you'll get such error.

Comment: Not if the `string` in the `TextBox` is all numeric.

Comment: +1 (not because the answer is great but) because -1 seems a bit harsh here - I personnaly think what Ali had to say was clear enough and certainly not worth -1.